# Row Click Event in vaadin-grid polymer

Tags: javascript, web-component, polymer-2.x, vaadin-grid

I have a requirement where a user selects a row(or a cell, for that matter) and presses some key(such as `Enter`, this is configurable) and I need to take some action based on the key pressed (such as opening a dialog with detailed information about the row).

As I was looking in the code, I stumbled upon a **key event handler** in [vaadin-grid-keyboard-navigation-mixin.html](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid/blob/v5.2.5/src/vaadin-grid-keyboard-navigation-mixin.html#L71) . But the `_onKeyDown` method handles only some specific keys. And I am not sure how to pass a callback to that function.

Any ideas regarding how this can be done. I just want to attach an key event handler to each cell, that capture the key event(again this is not fixed), and execute appropriate method.

I hope that I have been able to convey my intentions.

Thanks

Comment: Well can you bit explain more? what exactly is the key event?

Comment: One can easily navigate between cells in vaadin-grid, using the `Arrow` keys. Pressing the `Arrow` key generates a `KeyEvent` which is handled (see the link). I want to extend this functionality.

Comment: `this.addEventListener('keydown', this._bindMultiEvts); _bindMultiEvts(e){ this._onKeyDown; this._anOther; }` As such.

Comment: @Jai , yes but how to achieve this? I have implemented a double-click event handler by defining `on-dblclick` on each column.

Answer (score 0):

Your class has to implement KeyNotifier, then you can add a keyPressListener i.e. :

```
addKeyPressListener(Key.ARROW_DOWN, event -> anAwesomeFuncion());
```

Comment: This is in Java. I am trying to find solutions in JavaScript.